Как разрешить постепенный ввод текста по маске?
Regex — мощный инструмент, позволяющий проверять соответствие заданной маске.
Начиная с версии .NET 7.0 была введена поддержка генератора источника RegexGenerator — в своём коде использую его.
Для погружения в контекст возьмём валидацию номера телефона для PhoneNumberTextBox.
К примеру, если дан следующий Regex:
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="Regex"/>, которому соответствует только формат "+7 (XXX) XXX-XX-XX"
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Соответствие маске номера телефона</returns>
[GeneratedRegex(@"^\+7 \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$")]
private static partial Regex PhoneNumberOnlyRegex();

И следующий метод проверки:
/// <summary>
/// Метод, проверяющий соответствие текста заданному <see cref="Regex"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Text">Проверяемый текст</param>
/// <param name="Regex">Проверяющий <see cref="Regex"/></param>
/// <returns>Значение <see cref="bool"/> соответствия текста маске</returns>
private static bool IsTextAllowed(string Text, Regex Regex)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(Text);
}

То мы можем использовать этот метод следующим образом:
if (!IsTextAllowed(PhoneNumberTextBox.Text, PhoneNumberOnlyRegex()))
{
    PhoneNumberTextBox.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
}


Этот способ остаётся эффективным до тех пор, пока нам не придётся проверять правильность не всей строки, а вводимой последовательности. Вот тогда уже возникают проблемы.
К примеру:
Строка + 7 (000) 000-00-00 пройдёт по Regex, но как быть если нужно проверять правильность набора пользователем номера телефона? Вот он только наберёт + и Regex уже будет ругаться.
В каких-то случаях это может показаться незначительной проблемой, но что делать если разработчику нужно контролировать ввод каждого символа пользователя в UI, не давая пользователю ввести неверный символ? Например, через события PreviewTextInput и Pasting у элемента TextBox?
С событием PreviewTextInput, кстати, возникает другая проблема: оно не обрабатывает пробелы, вводимые пользователем, а реагирует только на вводимые символы. Как быть в таком случае?

По моему для такого не рационально использовать Regex, уж слишком тривиальная запись мобильного телефона. Лучше уж написать конечный автомат для этого, будет намного лучше, и состояние как раз можно будет проверять, вместо проверки части текста или полностью весь текст.

@evo, конечно, вы правы, это не совсем практично с этой точки зрения: можно создать свой пользовательский элемент с Placeholder или использовать такой инструмент, как ExceptionValidationRule. Но, тем не менее, если придётся столкнуться с ситуацией, когда нужно "жёстко контролировать" вводимый пользователем текст (или же хотя бы считывать эти действия), то можно будет воспользоваться представленным способом.

Предлагаю для решения данной проблемы ввести термины "строгая" и "нестрогая" маска. Что я имею в виду:

"Строгая (жёсткая / сильная) маска" — всеми привычный обычный Regex. В данном контексте — маска, проверяющая верность написания номера телефона и отсутствие некорректных символов на этапе, когда пользователь закончил ввод;
"Нестрогая (мягкая / слабая) маска" — такая маска номера телефона, которая позволяет осуществлять его постепенный ввод, но которая не позволяет вводить некорректные символы, как это делает "строгая маска".


Для реализации задуманного можно поступить следующим образом:

Исправить оригинальную маску — разделить её на незахватывающие группы:

/// <summary>
/// <see cref="Regex"/>, которому соответствует только формат "+7 (XXX) XXX-XX-XX"
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Соответствие маске номера телефона</returns>
[GeneratedRegex(@"^(?:\+7)(?: )(?:\(\d{3}\))(?: )(?:\d{3})(?:-)(?:\d{2})(?:-)(?:\d{2})$")]
private static partial Regex PhoneNumberOnlyRegex();


Создать "мягкую маску" для номера телефона. Она будет выглядеть так:

/// <summary>
/// <see cref="Regex"/> набираемого формата "+7 (XXX) XXX-XX-XX"
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Соответствие маске набираемого номера телефона</returns>
[GeneratedRegex(@"^(?:\+)?(?:7)?(?: )?(?:\()?(?:\d{0,3})(?:\))?(?: )?(?:\d{0,3})(?:-)?(?:\d{0,2})(?:-)?(?:\d{0,2})$")]
private static partial Regex OnPhoneNumberTypingRegex();


Использовать "мягкую маску" и уже написанный метод IsTextAllowed в событиях:


PreviewTextInput:

PhoneNumberTextBox.PreviewTextInput += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (sender is TextBox TextBox)
    {
        int CaretIndex = TextBox.CaretIndex;
        int SelectionStart = TextBox.SelectionStart;
        int SelectionLength = TextBox.SelectionLength;
        string NewText;

        if (SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            NewText = TextBox.Text.Remove(SelectionStart, SelectionLength).Insert(SelectionStart, e.Text);
        }

        else
        {
            NewText = TextBox.Text.Insert(CaretIndex, e.Text);
        }

        if (!IsTextAllowed(NewText, OnPhoneNumberTypingRegex()))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
};


PreviewKeyDown, которое будет выступать в роли обработчика пробелов:

PhoneNumberTextBox.PreviewKeyDown += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
        if (sender is TextBox TextBox)
        {
            int CaretIndex = TextBox.CaretIndex;
            int SelectionStart = TextBox.SelectionStart;
            int SelectionLength = TextBox.SelectionLength;
            string NewText;

            if (SelectionLength > 0)
            {
                NewText = TextBox.Text.Remove(SelectionStart, SelectionLength).Insert(SelectionStart, " ");
            }

            else
            {
                NewText = TextBox.Text.Insert(CaretIndex, " ");
            }

            if (!IsTextAllowed(NewText, OnPhoneNumberTypingRegex()))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
};


И в PhoneNumberTextBox_Pasting:

/// <summary>
/// Событие, срабатывающее перед вставкой символа/текста в <see href="PhoneNumberTextBox"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void PhoneNumberTextBox_Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
    {
        string Text = string.Empty;

        if (e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)) is string String)
        {
            Text = String;
        }

        if (sender is TextBox TextBox)
        {
            if (!IsTextAllowed(TextBox.Text + Text, OnPhoneNumberTypingRegex()))
            {
                e.CancelCommand();
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        e.CancelCommand();
    }
}


Перед сохранением/отправкой данных мы можем проверить правильность строки уже целиком по PhoneNumberOnlyRegex():

/// <summary>
/// Событие нажатия на кнопку "Сохранить"
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void SaveChangesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsTextAllowed(PhoneNumberTextBox.Text, PhoneNumberOnlyRegex()))
    {
        PhoneNumberTextBox.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;

        return;
    }
}


Как это по итогу работает:
Пользователь может набрать только:

один символ: +, (, );
два символа: -,   (пробел);
11 цифр.

Можно спокойно вставить образец +7 (000) 000-00-00, поудалять из ( ) цифры и написать другие. Маска "умная" — она соблюдает порядок набора и позволяет вписать только определённое количество цифр с соблюдением знаков.
То есть не получится сделать так:
+7 000 0000000()--

Но можно сделать так, поскольку порядок ввода не нарушен:
+7 000 00000-00

Как видите, ничего не мешает тому, чтобы совмещать как постепенную проверку, так и проверку целиком 

Обновлено: большое "Dziękuję" (спасибо) пользователю @Wiktor Stribiżew, без отличной маски которого я бы не усовершенствовал свой ответ — за что он и получил "+" от меня 

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Спасибо за очередной минус ПОСЛЕ редактирования ответа! Так приятно!

А зачем куча вырванных из контекста обработчиков, когда в WPF есть нормальные привязки и готовые инструменты валидации (документация) данных? Речь же шла про регулярки, верно? Тогда зачем всё остальное? Куда этот код-бихайнд впихнуть? Юзерконтрол? Так покажите его как решение, а то какое-то не туда и не сюда получается.

@aepot, "В каких-то случаях это может показаться незначительной проблемой, но что делать если разработчику нужно контролировать ввод каждого символа пользователя в UI, не давая пользователю ввести неверный символ? Например, через события PreviewTextInput и Pasting у элемента TextBox?"

@aepot, я не просто спросил — "какое регулярное выражение позволит ввести номер телефона пошагово?" Я также спросил и про способы контроля самого процесса ввода.

@aepot, вот никогда бы не подумал, что буду писать как один популярный питонист, но "я не вижу вашего предложенного решения. Была поставлена конкретная задача — её я и разбирал в ответе.  Есть альтернативные решения? Пожалуйста, демонстрируйте, для этого есть кнопка [Ответить]"

вы ушли от темы. Я написал про то что половина вашего ответа понятна только вам, а не о том, что он какой-то неправильный. Хотите кодить в стиле Windows Forms - пожалуйста, это ваш проект, вам и решать, какой код будет написан. Я писал о том, что обработчики событий непонятно, к чему прикручены, они вырваны из контекста. Разметка юзерконтрола тоже не видна. Ну да ладно, есть соседний ответ, он в принципе содержит всё что нужно.

@aepot, Возможно, у меня есть "ошибка XY", я не знаю, вам (и сторонним людям) виднее. В любом случае любая обратная реакция для меня дороже и ценнее молчаливого минуса. Надёюсь, не затягиваю с диалогом. По поводу контрола — это обычный TextBlock, без надстроек и изменений (не вижу смысла предоставлять его разметку). Почему же "обработчики вырванны из контекста"? Я предоставил вариант без использования сторонних контролов и библиотек. "Есть соседний ответ, он в принципе содержит всё что нужно" — только отчасти, ведь в ТЗ я описал, что мне нужна работающая обработка поведения через события

@aepot, может этот код абсолютно никто не будет применять на практике (я и не призываю), но, как мне кажется, в качестве просто идеи и интересной реализации, он заслуживает "право на жизнь"

Для финальной валидации используйте ваше регурярное выражение.
Для проверки частичного ввода используйте
^\+(?:7(?: (?:\((?:\d{1,3}(?:\)(?: (?:\d{1,3}(?:-(?:\d{1,2}(?:-\d{0,2})?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?$

См. пример работы регулярного выражения.

@Chaos_Sower, конечный автомат напишите, за то время что вы тратите на регулярные выражения уже давно можно было написать его, и не ломать голову.

@evo, извините, я ранее не сталкивался с термином "конечный автомат" — просветите?

@Chaos_Sower https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82
